# Ошибка при изменении стиля

Tags: javascript, css

В этой строке (javaScript, Google Chrome, Инструменты разработчика)

```
document.getElementById("logo_text2").style.top = '-10px';
```

постоянно вылетает ошибка рода

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

а в этом коде

```
document.getElementById("logo_text2").style.top = '10px';
```

ошибок нет

Подскажите, что это может быть?

P.S. Больше кода дать не могу, т.к. это к делу не относится.
Блок "logo_text2" существует и существовал. Скрипт работает, но эта ошибка меня как-то смущает.

```
function phraseGet() {
    var request = getXmlHttp();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 && window.i == 0) {
            document.getElementById('logo_text2').innerHTML = request.responseText;

        }
    }

    request.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("&act=get_phrase");
    if (window.i == 0) {
        document.getElementById("logo_text2").style.top = '-10px';
    }
}
setInterval(function() {phraseGet()}, 30000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, элемент у вас "мигающий": то он есть на странице, то его нет. Попробуйте вызвать "ошибочный" код из консоли.

Comment: Элемент не мигающий. Это на 99,9% я в этом уверен

Comment: Значит, надо больше информации. В идеале - сама страница, залитая на хостинг и вызывающая эту ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

А точно ли существует элемент с id "logo_text2"? Скорее нет, чем да

Comment: Даю 90%, что блок "есть", но скрипт выполняется из head(или просто до блока) без привязки к document.ready.

Comment: Точно, вероятнее всего

Comment: Проблема в том, что 

document.getElementById("logo_text2").style.top = '10px';

выполняется без ошибок

Comment: Надеюсь что ошибаюсь, но для того чтобы увидеть результат изменения стиля `top` у элемента должен быть прописан стиль `position:absolute` либо `position:fixed`
****
Но с тем что ошибок нет - скорее всего я прав... Печаль

Comment: Даже без позицирнирования не должно быть такой ошибки. Ошибка четко говорит, что document.getElementById вернул null.
Нужен пример, где это не работает

Comment: Так вы написали что у вас нет ошибки.

    onload = function(){
         //  тут ваш код
    }

вместо просто тупо

    // ваш код

Comment: Кстати - если `document.getElementById(someFuckingLolOmgNonExistingId)` ничего не вернуло, может стоит задуматься о том что я написал выше?

А еще лучше начать изучения javascript'а как и все смертные - со статей и книг.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, что выводит

`console.log(document.getElementById("logo_text2"))
console.log(document.getElementById("logo_text2").style)
console.log(document.getElementById("logo_text2").style.top)`

возможно это даст вам больше информации для отладки.

Comment: В ответ на первое он мне дает сам элемент
На второе спойлер с заголовком "CSSStyleDeclaration"
А на 3-е "-10px"
По идее, так и должно быть

Comment: Какой смысл делать `console.log`? Аффтар 99% пишет код не в `onload` и абсолютно не знает и, тем более - не понимает языка.

В его коде `document.getElementById("logo_text2")` вернуло `null`, в `console.log(document.getElementById("logo_text2"))` - вернуло элемент...

*"Странно"* не правда-ли? =)

Comment: Да блин, эллемент существует и существовал всегда. И он срабатывает после правильного запроса ajax. И такую ошибку выдает один раз, хотя такой кода выполняется каждые 30 сек и onload

Answer (score 0):

Тоже была проблема подобного рода. Помогло когда убрал скобки:

...

setInterval(function() {phraseGet()}, 30000)

на

setInterval(function() {phraseGet}, 30000)

Но если точнее, то у меня запись такого вида:

setInterval(phraseGet, 30000);